# I'm trying to establish an SSL-Connection. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, connection, client-server

This is the Server-Source:

```
package main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.security.KeyStore;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;

public class SslReverseEchoer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String ksName = "keystore.jks";
        char ksPass[] = "".toCharArray();
        char ctPass[] = "".toCharArray();
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(ksName), ksPass);
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(ks, ctPass);
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket s = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(8888);
        SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) s.accept();
        BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                c.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                c.getInputStream()));
        String m = "Welcome to SSL Reverse Echo Server."
                + " Please type in some words.";
        w.write(m, 0, m.length());
        w.newLine();
        w.flush();
        while ((m = r.readLine()) != null) {
            if (m.equals("."))
                break;
            char[] a = m.toCharArray();
            int n = a.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
                char t = a[i];
                a[i] = a[n - 1 - i];
                a[n - i - 1] = t;
            }
            w.write(a, 0, n);
            w.newLine();
            w.flush();
        }
        w.close();
        r.close();
        c.close();
        s.close();
    }
}
```

This is the Client-Code:

```
package main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class SslSocketClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String ksName = "keystore.jks";
        char ksPass[] = "".toCharArray();
        char ctPass[] = "".toCharArray();
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(ksName), ksPass);
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(ks, ctPass);
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintStream out = System.out;

        SSLSocketFactory f = (SSLSocketFactory) sc.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("localhost", 8888);
        c.startHandshake();
        BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                c.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                c.getInputStream()));
        String m = null;
        while ((m = r.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(m);
            m = in.readLine();
            w.write(m, 0, m.length());
            w.newLine();
            w.flush();
        }
        w.close();
        r.close();
        c.close();
    }
}
```

When I try to run them, I get the following Errors:

Client:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Server:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

I am not very experienced in programming, so I (think I) know what the Error-Messages mean, but I have no idea how to solve it.
The two keystores are in place. One is holding the Keypair and the other holds a Certificate generated from that Keypair. (all passwords removed for testing)
I have searched through the internet for quite some time, but I have found only poor explaination on thei, because most of the SSL-Connections try to connect to a web-server and not a self-made one.
In the end, I want to have two Java-Applications transmitting data through a SECURED SSL-Connection. This is NOT going to be a HTTPS-Server.

Comment: Is the certificate certified by a trusted verifier?

Comment: No, I have created the certificate myself, but I don't think that is the issue...

Comment: I believe your server has to designate a self-signed certificate as trusted by passing an array of TrustManagers as the SSLContext.init method's second argument.  You can get that array from a [TrustManagerFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/TrustManagerFactory.html) after calling one of its `init` methods.  I think you also need to set your certificates as trusted in the keystore (such as with keytool's `-importcert -trustcacerts` option).